# How to Find SUM of 5 Most Recent Records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum

This seems like it should be a simple answer, but I have been away from MySQL for quite some time... I've lost a lot of what I used to know.  The scenario is this:  I am tracking my bowling scores and want to find the series total of my most recent 5 games.  The structure of the table is simple:  scoreID (auto incrementing ID), scoreDate (date of the game bowled), and scoreValue (game scores).

I can return my latest 5 games with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY scoreID DESC LIMIT 5;
```

So far, so good. Where I am getting confused is if I attempt to return the sum of those games by doing the following:

```
SELECT SUM(scoreValue) FROM scores ORDER BY scoreID DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Obviously, that isn't correct, because if I do that, I just end up with the sum of every game I have in the database.  Not what I'm looking for.  I cannot remember how to just isolate the latest 5 games to get the sum for only those games.  Any reminders / refreshers / advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `SELECT SUM(..) FROM (SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY scoreID DESC LIMIT 5
)`a if that is not want you are looking for see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the help!  It's all slowly coming back to me...

Answer (score 1):

Take a subquery of the limit 5 query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(scoreValue) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT scoreValue
    FROM scores
    ORDER BY scoreID DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t;
```